# Flask redirect url_for changing type of parameter

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

I have the following code in Flask/python that involves a variable years that is a list of ints. However, when I use `return redirect(url_for(...`, years becomes unicode and if it had been [2015, 2014], it becomes '[','2','0','1','5',' ', etc...

```
@main.route('/search', methods=('GET','POST'))
def fysearch():
    form = SelectYear()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        years = form.years.data
        return redirect(url_for('.yearresults', years=years))
    return render_template('select_year.html', form=form)
```

When I print the type of each element in years above, it is a normal int as I want it to be. Once it is passed into the redirect url_for, that is when years turns into unicode.

```
@main.route('/searchresults/<years>')
def yearresults(years):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    print type(years)
    pagination = Grant.query.filter(Grant.fy.in_(years)).\
            paginate(page, per_page=current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)
    return render_template('yearresults.html', years=years, entries=pagination.items, pagination=pagination
```

I know there are ways to revert years back to a list of ints after it has been passed to `yearresults(years)` like years=json.loads(years) or replacing the [ and ] and splitting, but I was wondering if there is a different way to fix this issue. I have thought about a converter in the url routing, but I am not sure how that works since I am using flask blueprints. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) returns a URL, which is effectively a string - you can't mix a list of ints into a value that's effectively a string (in better languages/frameworks you will get a type error, more work that way but less prone to conceptual errors like what you are experiencing).  You can check simply by returning the result of `url_for('.yearresults', years=years)` and see that the value looks something like `/yearresults/%5B2014%2C%202015%5D`.  Clearly that value in place for `year` is a string as that is the default converter (since you did not define one).  So the lazy way out is to encode `years` with JSON or some sort of string format and decode that on the `yearresults` handler, however you had the right idea with using a [converter](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#custom-converters) which is from the werkzeug package.

Anyway, putting that together you could do something like this:

```
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter
from werkzeug.routing import ValidationError

class ListOfIntConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map):
        super(ListOfIntConverter, self).__init__(url_map)

    def validate(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            return False

        for i in value:
            if not isinstance(i, int):
                return False

        return True

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return [int(i) for i in value.split(',')]
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            raise ValidationError()

    def to_url(self, value):
        if not self.validate(value):
            # Or your specific exception because this should be from the
            # program.
            raise ValueError
        return ','.join(unicode(v) for v in value)

app.url_map.converters['listofint'] = ListOfIntConverter

@app.route('/years/<listofint:years>')
def years(years):
    return '%d, %s' % (len(years), years)
```

This has the advantage of generating a 404 directly when the input to this route do not match (i.e. someone supplying a string for `<years>`), and avoids the `%` encoded form of `[`, `]`, and  from a JSON (or the repr) based encoding (`%5B2014%2C%202015%5D` looks way ugly when compared to `2014,2015`).

Getting the converter into a specific blueprint (and also the unit tests for that) is your exercise.